# Relacionamento em tabela de banco de dados

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, modelagem, tabela-banco-de-dados, relacionamento

Tenho um formulário de cadastro onde contém informações pessoais, profissionais, adicionais, financeiras e produção, minha dúvida, como dá muitas colunas, acredito que mais de 50 campos.

É aconselhável deixar tudo em uma tabela? Ou separá-las e relacionar 1:1?

Comment: As informações não estão claras quanto ao que você quer dizer com profissionais, adicionais, produção, financeiras... O conhecimento do domínio é muito importante durante a modelagem.

Comment: existem várias áreas no formulário de cadastro, áreas como:Informações pessoais, profissionais, financeira, adicionais e de produção, onde juntando todos os campos dará mais de 50 colunas

Comment: Eu diria que você deve separar os campos em tabelas conforme fizerem sentido e, principalmente, se existir potencial de reuso. Por exemplo, o que são informações "profissionais"? Seria o tipo de emprego que um cliente tem? Por que se for, clientes diferentes podem ter o mesmo emprego, então faz todo o sentido separar as tabelas. Forneça mais detalhes e, se possível, foque em alguns dos campos que você tem mais dúvida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe algum motivo para separar? Essa é a questão. Quase sempre não precisa. Geralmente há um pequena perda de performance (pode ser em alguns casos haver melhora, mas teria que analisar o problema, não é comum) já que teria quer ler mais de um logar diferente, ter que fazer buscas separadas e teria uma complicação extra nas consultas. Pra que fazer isso então? Qual o ganho?

Pode até ser que queira montar um modelo lógico onde fique separado, mas o modelo físico (que é o que mais conta para o banco de dados, e muitos desenvolvedores acham que só ele existe) não costuma se beneficiar disto.

Tudo que for decidir fazer tem que se perguntar porque fazer. Se fizer gratuitamente, não deve fazer. Se não consegue explicar um motivo ou se leu em algum lugar mandando fazer e não viu uma explicação plausível do motivo para fazer, não deve fazer. Infelizmente vez ou outra encontramos recomendações, normalmente chamadas de "boas práticas", até com explicações plausíveis, mas ou que estão erradas ou que não se aplicam ao contexto que o programador inexperiente está enfrentando.

Se o gerenciador de banco de dados permite centenas de colunas, pode usá-las. Pra falar a verdade é muito comum que as tabelas costumem ter mais 10 colunas, então me parece que isso não é muito não, pelo contrário. Mesmo que fosse, ainda teria que justificar tecnicamente a decisão de separar, o que costuma ser difícil porque quase sempre é "errado".

Se ainda tiver dúvida e tiver um exemplo mais concreto pode fazer uma nova pergunta para analisarmos. Mas é muito provável que a resposta ainda seja manter uma tabela só.

Comment: A ficha de inscrição possui mais de 100 campos, a questão de dividir,acredito, é mais pra facilitar na manutenção

Comment: Na pergunta colocou 10, mas ainda assim não muda a resposta. Se quer dividir tente mostrar porque facilitaria a manutenção. Ter que mexer em dois lugares, pra mim dificulta.

Comment: uhm, entendo, mas n ficaria melhor até mesmo pra manter a query na hora do insert e update ?

Comment: Como eu disse na resposta, depende, mas na minha opinião é exatamente o oposto. Se acha melhor, pode tentar demonstrar isso. *Query* que envolva mais de uma tabela sempre é mais complexa de escrever, mesmo que não muito, e bem mais complexa do banco de dados processar.

Comment: entendo, obrigado !